# how to include external jar in android app for android custom build

Tags: android, build, jar, external, rom

I am trying to build a custom rom using android custom build project. I want to add one android application to it in which there is one external jar.  But whenever I run 'mm' (i.e make) in /package/apps/myApp it gives error 41 in which it is not able to recognize classes and functions from that external jar. Although eclipse is recognizing that jar and app is running perfect in eclipse but 'mm' is not able to compile it. What should i do?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the Android.mk file inside the **Calculator** app. It uses external jars.
I am also pasting a sample mk file that i used for my own app. You can use it:

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libguava libgcm android-support-v4

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := SampleApp

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libguava:guava-11.0.jar libgcm:gcm.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH)

libguava and libgcm are just two namespaces(You can use your own names) for the two jars:guava-11.0.jar and gcm.jar(I have used these jars in my project) respectively. I have kept the jars inside the project folder. If you have kept the jars inside libs folder use libguava:libs/guava-11.0.jar.Also, don't use *mm*. Use *make*, but don't do *make clean* before it else it will remove the entire build directory and start from scratch(take a lot of time) Please accept as solution if it works....Thanks

Comment: I've tried the same way. Buid runs without errors, but lib is not included into compiled apk. How can i solve this?